# Unable to move indicator to active link with NavLink in React Router 6.4.3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

So, there are 5 NavLink's in my navbar, I'm trying to make indicator move when link is clicked and it works, but only before page reload.
Down are my js and scss files for you to see.

scss for indicator

```
#marker {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 41px;
height: 41px;
transition: 0.5s;
z-index: 1;
}

#marker::before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: -10px;
left: 20%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
width: 40px;
height: 35px;
border-radius: 8px;
background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(58, 134, 255), 0 0 20px rgb(255, 255, 255),
    0 0 40px #fff, 0 0 80px #fff, 0 0 160px rgb(58, 134, 255);
}
```

[image: working image]

[image: here the indicator doesnt move]

Part of js file with NavLink, this code loops through li and deletes .active or gives it if item was clicked

```
const Sidebar = () => {
const marker = document.getElementById('marker')
const items = document.querySelectorAll('ul li')
function indicator(e) {
    marker.style.left = e.offsetLeft + 'px'
    marker.style.width = e.offsetWidth + 'px'
}

items.forEach((link) => {
    link.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        indicator(e.target)
    })
})

function activeLink() {
    const current = document.querySelector('.active')
    indicator(current)
}

items.forEach((link) => {
    link.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
        activeLink()
    })
})

const isActive = ({ isActive }) => (isActive ? 'active' : '')

<div className="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li className="list">
                    <NavLink to="/about" className={isActive}>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon
                            className="icon"
                            icon={faInfo}
                        ></FontAwesomeIcon>
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
                <div id="marker"></div>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: What `NavLink`s and navbar are you referring to? We can't help resolve issues with code we can't see. Can you edit the post to include a relevant [mcve] for the code you are working with?

Comment: sorry for the inconveniences

Comment: The `NavLink` already has and handles an `"active"` class by default, there shouldn't be much of that logic you need to duplicate yourself. Would it be possible for you to standup a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of this code that we could inspect live? Also just FYI, directly querying the DOM is often considered anti-pattern in React, use React refs to access underlying DOMNodes or just directly attach event handlers to the rendered elements.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-andras-knn6er  , iwhen indicator stops working go to sidebar.js change something and save, this will make it work again

Comment: Ok, thanks. Taking a look now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NavLink` component already has and handles an `active` state and conditionally applies an `"active"` class by default. Querying the DOM directly is also considered an anti-pattern in React. You should instead use React refs to query underlying DOMNodes or directly attach event handlers to elements.

The following snippet pair also adds "click" and "mouseover" event handlers each render cycle by they are never removed.

```
const items = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');
...
items.forEach((link) => {
  link.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    indicator(e.target);
  });
});
items.forEach((link) => {
  link.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
    activeLink();
  });
});
```

Relying on querying the DOM and mouseover events can be problematic since these all exist ***outside*** React.

I suggest the following refactor:

Define the link data in an array that can be easily mapped to menu items.

```
const links = [
  {
    to: "/about",
    icon: faInfo,
    label: "About"
  },
  {
    to: "/portfolio",
    icon: faSuitcase,
    label: "Works"
  },
  {
    to: "/",
    icon: faUser,
    label: "Home"
  },
  {
    to: "/contact",
    icon: faContactBook,
    label: "Contact"
  },
  {
    to: "/links",
    icon: faLink,
    label: "Links"
  }
];
```

Use React refs to create, attach, and hold references to the link item DOMNodes. The `links` array will be mapped to list items rendering the `NavLink` component, and the `NavLink` component will use the `children` render function so it's passing the `isActive` prop. Abstract the "children" into a React component that can call a function to set which menu item's DOMNode is the active node in the parent.

```
const SidebarItem = ({ isActive, link, setIsActive }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isActive) setIsActive();
  }, [isActive, setIsActive]);

  return (
    <>
      <FontAwesomeIcon className="icon" icon={link.icon} />
      <span className="text">{link.label}</span>
    </>
  );
};

const Sidebar = () => {
  const markerRef = useRef();
  const linkRefs = useRef([]);
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);

  linkRefs.current = links.map((_, i) => linkRefs.current[i] ?? createRef());

  useEffect(() => {
    if (anchorEl) {
      markerRef.current.style.left = anchorEl.offsetLeft + "px";
      markerRef.current.style.width = anchorEl.offsetWidth + "px";
    }
  }, [anchorEl]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="navigation">
        <ul>
          {links.map((link, index) => (
            <li key={link.to}>
              <NavLink ref={linkRefs.current[index]} to={link.to}>
                {({ isActive }) => (
                  <SidebarItem
                    {...{
                      isActive,
                      link,
                      setIsActive: () =>
                        setAnchorEl(linkRefs.current[index].current)
                    }}
                  />
                )}
              </NavLink>
            </li>
          ))}
          <div ref={markerRef} id="marker"></div>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit unable-to-move-indicator-to-active-link-with-navlink-in-react-router-6-4-3]